# Bootstrap How to change style of links in table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, html-table

I have a little problem, cause I would like to change color of my link when it's hover, and also his background. I should add another class for a? And then style it? I tried but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('title', 'Przychodnia')


@section('content')

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="intro-text text-center">{{$doctorsDeadlines['lekarz']['imie']}} {{$doctorsDeadlines['lekarz']['nazwisko']}}
                </h2>
                <hr>
                <hr class="visible-xs">
                <h4 class="text-center">Terminarz</h4>
                <br/>
                <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        @foreach($doctorsDeadlines['terminy'] as $date => $hours)
                            <th>{{$date}}</th>
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        @foreach($doctorsDeadlines['terminy'] as $date => $hours)
                        <td>
                            @foreach($hours as $hour )
                                <a href="#">{{$hour}}</a>
                            @endforeach

                        </td>
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>


                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below css

```
.hour{ color: red!important; }
.hour:hover{ color: #000!important; background-color:#fff!important; }
```

You can add your own color.

Comment: In my opinion this should work, but it doesn't. Maby there is soemthing wrong with my code?

Comment: I can see your link, its working dude, if you can not see then press ctrl+f5

Comment: Wow, that was problem with my phpStorm :D Reeeeaaalllly thanks for You :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover { color: <your choice> }
```

or

```
.yourClassNameForA:hover { color: <your choice> }
```

Comment: I tried like this but it doesn't work, my code doesn't react.

Comment: your css is included OR inline? if included then make sure that css is proper included, and you can try `!important` after css like `table a:hover{ color: #colorcode!important; }`, hope it works

Comment: Where is your css code? Please type complete question.

Comment: you want to add css in hours?

Comment: Yes, I want to change hover color and add background.

Answer (score 0):

```
table a:hover{
color: #colorcode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover {
background-color: lightgreen; color: brawn;}
a:link {
background-color: yellow;color: black;}
a:visited {
background-color: cyan; color: blue;}
```